# Hello World With NRF24L01

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have Arduino and a Duinotech NRF24L01, I am trying to send the string "Hello world" with maniacs bug RF24 library however, I think it cannot detect the incoming RF signal.

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include "nRF24L01.h"
    #include "RF24.h"

    RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN

    const uint64_t pipe = 0xF0F0F0F0E1L;
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      radio.begin();
      radio.openReadingPipe(0, pipe);
      radio.startListening();

    }

    void loop() {
      if (radio.available()) {
        char text[32] = "";
        radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
        Serial.println(text);
      }
      else {
        Serial.println("Data was not found"); 
      }
```

In the read code, it would always execute data was not found. This makes me think that maybe it does not find the RF signal at all.

Here is the code that writes the data.

```
 #include <SPI.h>
 #include "nRF24L01.h"
 #include "RF24.h"

 RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
 int text = 1;
 const uint64_t pipe = 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL;

 void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600); 
   radio.begin();
   radio.openWritingPipe(pipe);
   radio.stopListening();
 }
void loop() {
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text)); 
  Serial.println("Sending Data");
  delay(1000); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For the transmitter Instead of `const uint64_t pipe = 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL;` use `const byte address[6] = "00001";` as the address and then have you void setup like the code below

```
void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
}
```

Then ensure that you have a value set for the test variable to be transmitted as below

```
 void loop() {
      const char text[] = "Hello World"; 
      radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
      Serial.println("Sending Data");
      delay(1000);
    }
```

At the receiver end have this code running

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
}
void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    char text[32] = "";
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text); //This will print out the received value 
  }
}
```

PS: Ensure that all the connections are done to the right pins

AND you can test if the NRF24L01 chip is connected correctly by adding the code below

```
bool result = radio.isChipConnected ();

Serial.println (result);
```

it should print out a 1 to the serial monitor if the NRF24L01 chip is connected correctly